# How to correctly desugar syntactic tree? - reduction of data structure definition / constructor disabling

Tags: parsing, haskell, text-parsing, syntactic-sugar, haskell-parsing

I am developing a new language in Haskell and I run into a problem with syntactic tree `T` desugaring.

I have a set of functions `f1, f2,... fn`, which are simplifying the tree `T` from the "sugar". They are separated into different recursive functions so the code is more readable (each have some specific task and it is much simpler to understand what they are doing than if they were implemented into one recursion).

The composed function for desugaring looks like

```
f :: T -> T
f = f1 . f2 . f3 . ... . fn
```

I have read (and I think) that the best practice in Haskell is, that you represent data in a way, they can't get a wrong/undefined/impossible value. The problem is, that each function `f1`,...,`fn` basically reduce the type T by some constructors. (eg. f1 applied to T removes some sugar, represented by some constructor, which can't appear in any later function `f2`,...,`fn`).

So to hold the best practices, I would have to somehow define types `T1, T2,..., Tn`, where

```
f1 :: T -> T1
f2 :: T1 -> T2
...
fn :: Tn-1 -> Tn
```

**How can I do this please?** I was thinking about using Haskell templates but it seems to me like an overkill. **Is there some polymorphism approach to that? Can this implementation be overcome without sacrificing code readability?**

#### Why does it matter?

I said the best practices, which might be considered by community as opinion based, so I explain it further.

All functions `f1, f2,...,fn` are counting on their predecessor to their job. But if the type `T` is passed from and to `f1, f2,...,fn`, the compiler

1. Makes many warning about pattern matching (if they are not properly handled by `error "This shouldn't be possible"`)
2. I don't get so good compilation check about the code correctness. Compiler can't know, whether I don't do something, which shouldn't be possible. (eg. using syntactic sugar, which was already removed)

#### A concrete example

For simplicity, let's suppose the Haskell Template `Language.Haskell.TH.Exp`. If I want to use the same approach for language processing, I might want to define `f1` as function, which substitutes all `ArithSeqE` (`[ 1 ,2 .. 10 ]`) for `AppE`s (`f x`) generating the arithmetic sequence.

Now, I would like to (somehow) define a new type out of `Language.Haskell.TH.Exp` - `T1`, which forbids usage of constructor `ArithSeqE`, so the compiler know that it can't be in any further `T2,T3,...Tn` and therefore `f2,f3,...,fn` don't have to pattern match it and can't use it.

Comment: [Trees That Grow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/trees-that-grow-2.pdf) describes GHC's solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution to only some of your problems. I hope that even a partial solution may inspire better ideas.

My idea is to parameterize your sum type, with one type parameter per constructor you may eliminate. The idea is that, while the constructors will remain, you can parameterize them so that they are uninhabited. This way, while the compiler will still, alas, remind you to match the impossible constructors, it will be impossible for one of your desugaring steps to actually leave such a constructor in place.

Suppose you have this type:

```
data Expr = Value Int
          | Pair Value Value
          | Values [Expr]
```

You might have a desugaring step that replaces each Pair with a two-element Values constructor. First, we need to replace the two-field constructor with a one-field constructor:

```
data PairContents = PairContents Value Value
data Expr = Value Int
          | Pair PairContents
          | Values [Expr]
```

Then, we add a type parameter that allows us to either allow or forbid a PairContents:

```
newtype No x = No Void
data PairContents = PairContents Value Value
data Expr pairf = Value Int
                | Pair (pairf PairContents)
                | Values [Expr]
```

Now, a refactoring step that removes all Pair constructors can have the type

```
desugarPairs :: Expr Identity -> Expr No
```

It's impossible for an `Expr No` to contain any `Pair` constructor, because the type of its `Pair` field is `No PairContents`, which is `Void`, and thus uninhabitable.

As I say, there are several problems with my approach. It means you need 10 type parameters if you have 10 refactoring steps that each desugar one construct; you still have to pattern-match on `Pair` in the next step even though you know it's impossible. I hope someone will have a better suggestion. But at least this accomplishes something: your refactoring steps can be relied on to have removed all of the sugar they claim to.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71272150/converting-between-variants-of-a-data-type) (my own question). In the first version of my code I also had an uninhabited type, but it looks like it is not necessary with GADTs. With DataKinds `Expr` can have a more sophisticated parameter, one that encodes presence or absence of an arbitrary number of constructors in a single parameter (a type list for example).