# Converting between variants of a data type

Tags: haskell, gadt, data-kinds

Suppose I want to create two variations of a data type, one that has a certain constructor and one that does not have it, otherwise they are identical. I came up with this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Foo (a :: Bool) where
  A :: Int -> Foo True
  B :: String -> Foo a
  C :: [Int] -> [String] -> Foo a
  None :: Foo a
```

So far so good. I have `Foo True` which has `A` data constructor enabled, and `Foo False` that has it effectively disabled. But there is a problem.

I cannot come up with a terse way to transform `Foo True` to `Foo False`. Here's what works:

```hs
removeA :: Foo True -> Foo False
removeA (A _) = None
removeA (B x) = B x
removeA (C xs ys) = C xs ys
removeA None = None
```

but this is ugly since I have to duplicate all the non-A constructors at both sides of `=`.

Here's what doesn't work:

```hs
removeA :: Foo True -> Foo False
removeA (A _) = None
removeA a = a -- type mismatch: Foo True vs Foo False
removeA a = coerce a -- type mismatch: True vs False
```

I understand why the first attempt doesn't work, but what about the second? Isn't it supposed to be a phantom type? If not, can I force it to become one? What other options are there?

A smaller problem is that when I try to pattern match a `Foo False` on `A`, GHC only emits a warning. Can it be made into a full blown error without enabling `-Werror` and the like?

Comment: I suspect that working out when `coerce` is safe is Hard with a capital H. I'm told that even checking whether a set of constructors is complete is already hard in GADT land, and this problem is strictly harder -- you need to first find the set of remaining constructors that makes the match complete, then check that all their return types unify with both the source and target types you're asking for in `coerce`, and then you probably need to check a few more things like that there aren't any dictionaries or type families or data families that mention the parameter... who knows what else.

Comment: @DanielWagner Hmmm. I don't quite get it. The [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/coercible.pdf) says "All parameters of a type or data family have nominal role, because they could be inspected by the type family instances. For similar reasons, the non-uniform parameters to GADTs are also required to be nominal." But I don't understand the second sentence at all. What are these reasons?

Comment: Well, the most obvious reason is that `coerce :: Foo True -> Foo False` would be bad to allow wholesale. Then the `e` in `case coerce A :: Foo False of A -> e` would have the constraint `True ~ False` in scope, from which you can make anything with a few contortions.

Comment: @DanielWagner do you need `coerce` to arrive to that? I don't see where you can use the fact that the expression is coerced. I can just write `case None::Foo False of {A -> 0; None -> 1}` but then GHC warns about inaccessible code.

Comment: @DanielWagner So GCC probably won't even consider this a pattern match. Hmm this would mean `coerce A :: Foo False` can never be matched against anything, so kind of `undefined`, which I guess is bad.

Comment: Yes, you can write `case None of A -> e`, but then `e` will not be executed, so it's fine for it to have weird/wrong type equalities in its context.